# PG::DatatypeMismatch: ERROR: argument of WHERE must be type boolean, not type integer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I am getting this error in the Production site and this is the code in my views

```
<%= form_for [:admin, @course], :remote => true do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :name %>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
  <%= f.label :duration %> 
  <%= f.number_field :duration, class: "input-md form-control mb-20"%> 
  <%= f.label :program_id %> 
  <%= f.collection_select :program_id, Program.where('id'), :id, :name, {}, {class: "input-md form-control mb-20" } %>
<%end%>
```

This works in my local server where i have sql db setup.

```
Program model
     has_many :courses
```

can anyone guide me?

Comment: Indeed, `Program.where('id')` makes on sense, what do you mean by that?

Comment: What do you want to pass through `Program.where('id')` ?

Comment: @ray I am trying to get all the program name in a dropdown through program_id,

Comment: @Penny, the syntax for doing that seems to be wrong. use this <% f.select :program_id, Program.all.collect { |p| [p.name, p.id] } %> . This will populate your dropdown with program names and the params will contain program id that you can save in your table.

Comment: `program_id` foreign key is present in @course object?

Comment: @SuganyaSelvarajan that doesnt work , it tells undefined local variable or method `id'

Comment: just replace "Program.where('id')" by "Program.all " it will work,

Comment: @ray yes program_id is there in the course table

Comment: @RiteshRanjan thanks it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where clause isn't calling anything to compare with, so PG doesn't know what to include in the results. A where clause must evaluate to true/false.

just replace

```
<%= f.collection_select :program_id, Program.where('id'), :id, :name, {}, {class: "input-md form-control mb-20" } %>
```

by

```
<%= f.collection_select :program_id, Program.all, :id, :name, {}, {class: "input-md form-control mb-20" } %>
```

If you have some problem with some of the Program in your data base, add a column as status in programs table and make changes here as

```
<%= f.collection_select :program_id, Program.where("status =?", true), :id, :name, {}, {class: "input-md form-control mb-20" } %>
```